# How to set cookie with QWebview in QML?

Tags: qml, qwebview

I am using QWebView in QML. I want to show web site that needs authentication. Data should be passed via standard cookie.
Any help? Additional link or example would be great.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the default QNetworkAccessManager used by webkit have its own (non-persistent) cookie jar, aka QNetworkCookieJar.

This will handle the sending and receiving of cookies during the life span of a QWebPage.

To keep the same cookie jar across multiple pages, you have to:

1. Create an instance of a QNetworkCookieJar, possibly subclassing
   it to make it persistent
2. attach this cookie jar to each newly
   created QWebPage

Example of a persistent cookie jar saved to settings:

```cpp
class PersistentCookieJar : public QNetworkCookieJar {
public:
    PersistentCookieJar(QObject *parent) : QNetworkCookieJar(parent) { load(); }
    ~PersistentCookieJar() { save(); }

public:
    void save()
    {
        QList<QNetworkCookie> list = allCookies();
        QByteArray data;
        foreach (QNetworkCookie cookie, list) {
            if (!cookie.isSessionCookie()) {
                data.append(cookie.toRawForm());
                data.append("\n");
            }
        }
        QSettings settings;
        settings.setValue("Cookies",data);
    }

    void load()
    {
        QSettings settings;
        QByteArray data = settings.value("Cookies").toByteArray();
        setAllCookies(QNetworkCookie::parseCookies(data));
    }
};
```

To use:

```cpp
QWebView* vw = new QWebView(this);
PersistenCookieJar* jar = new PersistenCookieJar(this);
vw->page()->networkAccessManager()->setCookieJar(jar);  // the jar is reparented to the page
jar->setParent(this);  // reparent to main widget to avoid destruction together with the page
```

Comment: Hint: If you the above code doesn't work for you then you can extend it and override the virtual cookiesForUrl(QUrl*) method. Gather the base class method cookies in there, add your permanent ones and return all of them. This way your cookie will be passed to any URL opened in the browser.