# How to set cookies for a WebView in qml

Tags: qml, qwebview, qt5.1

Currently I am trying to do this by accessing the “QWebView” object. Following is the code that I use:

```
QObject* window = getQmlWindow("appWindow"); // returns the top-level qml ApplicationWindow
QObject* webView = window->findChild<QObject*>("QWebView"); // WebView has an objectName = "QWebView"
QWebView* qWebView = static_cast<QWebView *>(webView); // Cast QObject to QWebView

qWebView->page()->networkAccessManager()->setCookieJar(cookies); // cookies is of type QNetworkCookieJar*
```

it gives a segmentation fault error while accessing networkAccessManager().

Am i doing it in the right way? Is there any other ways to set cookies for Qml WebView. I am using QtQuick 5.1 and QtWebKit 3.0.

Note:

1. This is a cross posting of the original [question](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/36103/)
2. There might be some similarity with the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336367/how-to-set-cookie-with-qwebview-in-qml),

   but it doesn't solve my question.

Comment: try to get `networkAccessManager` directly from the **declarative engine** and it won't need any **casting** to `QWebView` and then set your cookies.